# rotate multiple UIViews around a center point with rotation gesture

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, core-animation, uigesturerecognizer

I have 4 rectangular views which make up a square around the center of the screen, and I'm trying to figure out a way to spin the views around the center point of the screen when the user does a 2 finger rotation gesture. Can anyone help me figure out how to rotate 4 views around the center point of the screen instead of their own center?

Thanks...

Comment: Add them all to an empty view with its bounds constrained to their edges, then just rotate that view. 
Trying to move each view separately would require some math and a complex algorithm to handle it.

Comment: That's a good solution, but just for the sake of argument, lets say I want to try the harder approach, how could I go about doing that? I'm building an app to learn gesture recognizers, and I've got pan, so the rectangles can be dragged, and pinch that moves them in and out, but I want to rotate them around the center regardless of where they are in the superview.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IQGeometry to easily create your complex algorithm.

[IQGeometry](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQGeometry)

This framework contains all basic and some complex calculations for you.

Straight Solution to your harder approach.

1) Rotate your view by CGAffineTransformMakeRotation. Say 45 degree.

2) Now use IQGeometry+CGPoint function to calculate new center point of your view.

```
CGPoint CGPointRorate(CGPoint point/*CurrentCenterPoint of View*/, CGPoint basePoint/*Base Center Point around which we have to rotate*/, CGFloat angle/*Angle 45(Radian or angle try it your self)*/);
```

3) Set your view's center point to new centerPoint. and that's it.

4) Apply this algorithm to all your 4 views.